# Script isn't working in html

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic piece of code. I am attempting to collect a number from the user and change parts of the page based on that. Here is my code

```
<body>
    <h1> <span class ="magicNum" id ="magic"> ? </span></h1>
    <h2><span id ="output">Result</span></h2>
    <h2> Score: <span id = "score"> 0 </span></h2>
    <div class="wrapper" > 
    <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter your guess:"/>
    <button onclick="submit()"> Submit </button></div> <br>
    <div class="wrapper" > <button id ="playAgain" onclick="restart()"> Play Again? </button></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var magicNumber;
        var points = 0;
        function submit(){
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            var counter=document.getElementById('score');
            magicNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            question.innerHTML = magicNumber;
            if ((magicNumber == text) or ((text + 1) == magicNumber) or ((text - 1) == magicNumber)) {
                points++;
                counter.innerHTML = points;
                output.innerHTML = You Got Lucky!;
            } else {
                output.innerHTML = Bad luck. Try again;
            }
        }
        function restart() {
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            text.innerHTML= result;
            question.innerHTML=?;
            output.innerHTML=;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

My previous errors in similar scenarios were due to misspellings but I can't seem to find any of those cases. Is it because I am comparing numbers in the wrong way or not initializaing my variables properly or not retreiving items properly or soemthing else entirely? I can't figure out how to debug.

Edit: The script isn't working at all. I enter a number into my field and press the submit button which should trigger submit() but there is no result or change.

Comment: You don't mention specifically what is not working. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Um, is that the same thing that you have on your website? `output.innerHTML = You Got Lucky!;` is a syntax error, `question.innerHTML=?;` is a syntax error. There are two more of that kind.

Comment: Did you forget the quotation marks around string values such as `output.innerHTML = You Got Lucky!;`?

Comment: Take a look at this question to learn how to open a Javascript console in each browser: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers The console will readily point out any errors that it finds.

Comment: I elaborated on the problem and added the quotation marks (sorry, didn't realize I needed them). Still no change

Comment: @iswg, you can see my working snippet below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code;

- string not in quote `("this is a string")`
- The or in js is `||`
- In your restart function `result` is used but it is not defined. So instead of `text.innerHTML= result` you can do `text.innerHTML= ""`(it is all depend on what you want to do, but at least now it is syntactically correct) ;

```html
<h1> <span class ="magicNum" id ="magic"> ? </span></h1>
    <h2><span id ="output">Result</span></h2>
    <h2> Score: <span id = "score"> 0 </span></h2>
    <div class="wrapper" > 
    <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter your guess:"/>
    <button onclick="submit()"> Submit </button></div> <br>
    <div class="wrapper" > <button id ="playAgain" onclick="restart()"> Play Again? </button></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var magicNumber;
        var points = 0;
        function submit(){
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            var counter=document.getElementById('score');
            magicNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            question.innerHTML = magicNumber;
            if ((magicNumber == text) || ((text + 1) == magicNumber) || ((text - 1) == magicNumber)) {
                points++;
                counter.innerHTML = points;
                output.innerHTML = "You Got Lucky!";
            } else {
                output.innerHTML = "Bad luck. Try again";
            }
        }
        function restart() {
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            text.innerHTML= "";
            question.innerHTML="?";
            //output.innerHTML=;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: @YannChabot, I have just realized that the `result` in restart function is not defined. But I have updated the answer now

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript there is no "or" , you can use "||" as OR logical operator , https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code there was a lot of mistakes, undefined variables, string were not between quotes and and so on:

```
<body>
    <h1> <span class ="magicNum" id ="magic"> ? </span></h1>
    <h2><span id ="output">Result</span></h2>
    <h2> Score: <span id = "score"> 0 </span></h2>
    <div class="wrapper" > 
    <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter your guess:"/>
    <button onclick="submit()"> Submit </button></div> <br>
    <div class="wrapper" > <button id ="playAgain" onclick="restart()"> Play Again? </button></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var magicNumber;
        var points = 0;
        function submit(){
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            var counter=document.getElementById('score');
            magicNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            question.innerHTML = magicNumber;
            if ((magicNumber == text) || ((text + 1) == magicNumber) || ((text - 1) == magicNumber)) {
                points++;
                counter.innerHTML = points;
                output.innerHTML = "You Got Lucky!";
            } else {
                output.innerHTML = "Bad luck. Try again";
            }
        }
        function restart() {
            var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
            var question=document.getElementById('magic');
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            var result=document.getElementById('magic'); // was it the expected behavior ?
            text.innerHTML= result;
            question.innerHTML="?";
            output.innerHTML= "";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yg3hdfjw/1/